# How to remove the blank between div.sons?

Tags: html, css

Three div.sons were put vertically with no blank between them.
Here is the css code and displayed image.

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
div.father {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 364px;
  width: 364px;

}
div.son {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}
</style>

</header>
<body>
    <div class="father">
    <div class="son">box1</div> 
    <div class="son">box2</div>
    <div class="son">box3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

There is no blank between div.sons for the vertically displayed div.son.

Now let's make all div.sons horizontally displayed.

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
div.father {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 364px;
  width: 400px;

}
div.son {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>

</header>
<body>
    <div class="father">
    <div class="son">box1</div> 
    <div class="son">box2</div>
    <div class="son">box3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The displayed image is as the following.

[image]

How to remove all the blank between div.sons for the horizontally displayed image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to `div.son`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that arrises when you use `inline-block` is that whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen.

There are a few ways to remove that space

Like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/j6rcfkmz/

Answer (score 3):

add `float: left;` for son class in css

Answer (score 0):

Also **Flexbox** can be used.

```css
.son {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.son li {
  list-style:none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="son">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with using display inline-block, instead of this you should use float left on the elements with the class of 'son'.

Comment: Little more explanation would be more helpful for future readers.